# Is Spring Rest the implementation of JAX-RS or what implementation does Spring Rest use for REST support?

Tags: spring-boot

I know JAX-RS has many implementations like RESTEASY,Jersy,RestLet.But when i use Spring boot project i just need to add Spring-web dependency and i am ready to go for creating REST APIs.I want to know what is the implementation Spring Boot Rest uses to support REST ?

Answer (score 1):

[Difference between JAX-RS and Spring Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944777/difference-between-jax-rs-and-spring-rest)

hope that solves your problem or makes it a little clearer.